# Use flashlight as torch to take picture - textureview android

Tags: android, camera, android-camera2

I use https://github.com/natario1/CameraView lib in my app to take picture. I want flashlight always ON while taking picture. is it possible? lib provide

> cameraFlash="torch"

functionality but when I take picture flash light is blink. I don't want to blink flash while taking picture. can any one have solution for this or any other related lib or suggestion? thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

you can use default intent to capture the pic

use this code before calling camera intent

```
 if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M){
                CameraManager camManager = (CameraManager) getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE);
                String cameraId = null;
                try {
                    cameraId = camManager.getCameraIdList()[0];
                    camManager.setTorchMode(cameraId, true);
                }catch (CameraAccessException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
```

this will make flash torch ON meanwhile on it's **onActivityResult** you can set off the flashlight like this

```
camManager.setTorchMode(cameraId, false);
```

Comment: actually i want solution with  https://github.com/natario1/CameraView this lib but anyway thanks